# RegEx for three tricky string patterns

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I want to find out an Instagram username from a profile page.

The thing is users choose how to address their usernames. (So, it is tricky to make computer get the pattern with RegEx)

All of patterns I want to search are shown below (user posts their Instagram username using one of them):

- IG: @user-name
- I.G.: @user-name
- Instagram: @user-name

I thought of this logic below but I got completely lost searching in RegEx documentation or examples suitable for this search.

**My logic: ignorecase (IG or I.G. or I.G or instagram) + (possible space) + (possible :) + (possible space) + (possible @) + (username with - or _ in it) + (ends with space or new line or full stop)**

In a word, I'd like to select a word(username) after "instagram" or "IG" or "I.G" excluding unnecessary characters like ":", "@" or spaces.

How can I do this in RegEx? One-liner might be an efficient, yet elegant answer.

P.S. I want to do this with Python re.

Comment: `^(I\.?G\.?|Instagram) ?:? ?@?[-_a-z]+$`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/iRZByh/1

Comment: Thank you PM 77-1. But this regex is rather fixed. I wanted to find flexible patterns. They do or do not have spaces, hyphens underscore, or colon. Anyway, I upvoted your comment.

Comment: Why not just `\b(?:instagram|I\.?G\.?)\s?:?\s?@?(\w+(?:-\w+)*)` https://regex101.com/r/BY6Gyj/1 What are the allowed characters for the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My logic: ignorecase(IG or I.G. or I.G or instagram) + (possible space) + (possible :) + (possible space) + (possible @) + (username with - or _ in it) + (ends with space or new line or full stop)

First, on prefix part (IG and Instagram:). You can use `re.I` or `re.IGNORECASE` argument on `re.compile` function to ignore cases, on I.G and instagram. Then use the `|` or the `or` on regex terms.

```
r'(instagram|I\.*G\.*)'
```

Then escape the `.` and use the question mark `?` which indicates that it can either have one or none, also on possible space `\s` and possible colon `:`.

```
prefix = re.compile(r'(instagram|I\.*G\.*)\s?:?', re.IGNORECASE)
```

And then for the username. First, use the question mark `?` on `@` to indicate that it is optional. Then the two `(.*)` are the first and last (if any) part of the username separated by either dash or underscore `(-|_)?` which is also optional.
username = re.compile(r'@?(.*)(-|_)?(.*)\s?$')
Placing it altogether:

```
username_regex = re.compile(r'^(instagram|I\.?G\.?)\s?:?\s?(@?.*((-|_).*)?\s?)$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

I've performed some tests for this regex, here is the code.

```
import re

username_regex = re.compile(r'^(instagram|I\.?G\.?)\s?:?\s?(@?.*((-|_).*)?\s?)$', re.IGNORECASE)

tests = [
    'I.G.: @first-last',
    'I.G: @first-last',
    'I.g: @first-last',
    'I.g.: @first-last',
    'i.G: @first-last',
    'i.G.: @n-last',
    'i.g: @first-last',
    'i.g. @first-last',
    'I.G.:@first-last',
    'I.G@first-last',
    'I.g @first-last',
    'I.gfirst-last',
    'i.G: first_last',
    'i.G. first_last',
    'ig: first_last',
    'i.g. @first-last',
    'inStagram: @first-last',
    'instAgram: @first-last',
    'INSTAGRAM: @first-last',
]

not_matched = 0
for test in tests:
    searched = username_regex.search(test)

    if searched:
        print("MATCH ->", test)
        print(searched.group(), '\n\n')
    else:
        print("========", test)
        not_matched += 1

print(not_matched)
# >> 0
```

If you want to get the prefix and username, you can use the `group()` and `groups()` method. For example

```
searched.groups()
# ('I.G:', '@first-last', None, None)

searched.group(0) # 'I.G: @first-last'

# If you want to get the prefix
searched.group(1) # 'I.G:'

# If you want to get the username
searched.group(2) # '@first-last'
```

NOTE: It is possible that I am wrong here somewhere, if you found something wrong, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helps too. But this doesn't search for username "firstlast"(I mean no - or _). This is the test string I have made: "Instagram: firstlast". Could you help me further?

Comment: I forgot to add a `?` after the `(-|_)`. Thanks for that, I found a mistake from my regex pattern, when there is no - or _, it will still get the last name where it shouldn't. So I made it `((-|_).*)?` so if there are no separator `-` or `_` then it will only get the name that has one word.

Comment: It works! Thank you. And it seems that I get whole line for "user" and prefix for "pre" so I need to replace pre in user? (Did you get me?)

Comment: Eve, I saw your edit. And here is the result I get. 
instAgram: first-last
Here, I want to get only "first-last" from the "searched". What can I do?

Comment: On my comment, I decided to place the regex `pre` and `user` altogether and then I regrouped the prefix and username.

If you only want to get the "first-last", then use `searched.group(2)`. Or are you asking that it should not have a `@`?

Comment: Yes it is working with group(2). Can I remove @ from the result string with regex?(I get @firstlast something like this) If not possible, I can always use replace() to do this.

Comment: You can move the `(` on the regex pattern to exclude the `@` on the group (if it has one). 
So on this piece of regex pattern on the username part this `(@?.*` should be `@?(.*`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `match` and `group` like so:

```
>>> ss = ['IG: @user-name', 'I.G.: @user-name', 'Instagram: @user-name']
>>> m = re.search('(IG|I\.G\.|Instagram)\: @(.*)$', ss[0])
>>> m.group(0)
'IG: @user-name'
>>> m.group(1)
'IG'
>>> m.group(2)
'user-name'
>>> m = re.search('(IG|I\.G\.|Instagram)\: @(.*)$', ss[1])
>>> m.group(2)
'user-name'
>>> m = re.search('(IG|I\.G\.|Instagram)\: @(.*)$', ss[2])
>>> m.group(2)
'user-name'
>>> m = re.search('(IG|I\.G\.|Instagram)\: @(.*)$', 'now for something completely different')
>>> if m:
...   m.group(2)
>>>
```